# PHP Как преобразовать JSON UNICODE в TEXT

Tags: php, json, unicode

у меня есть такая проблема: Принимаю запрос с API телеграма на мой bot.php

```
$body = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$arr = json_decode($body, true); 
$arr1 = print_r($body, true);
file_put_contents('apidata.txt', "DATA_OT_BOTA: $arr1", FILE_APPEND);
```

В текстовике apidata.txt появлетсяя такое:

```
{"update_id":561451711,
"message":{"message_id":301,"from":{"id":5676047177,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Marshall","username":"idaqipyshim7c","language_code":"ru"},"chat":{"id":5676047177,"first_name":"Mall","username":"idaqipm7c","type":"private"},"date":1667695735,"text":"\u043a\u043f\u0443\u043a\u043f\u0443\u043a\u043f"}}
```

Как мне спарсить "text":"\u043a\u043f\u0443\u043a\u043f\u0443\u043a\u043f" и преобразовать его из юникода в обычный текст? Ничего не помогает

Comment: json_decode("\u043a\u043f.....");

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php

Comment: json_decode дает кракозяблы

Comment: Исходя из вашего кода,  в `apidata.txt` не может появиться такой текст. Он мог бы там быть, если бы вы записывали переменную `$body` в файл, а вы пишите вывод массива в текстовом виде, который отличается от представленного вами текста

Comment: `json_decode` не даёт кракозяблы. Можете проверить в любом компиляторе php онлайн. Для того чтобы увидеть русский текст в json'не, сделайте `json_decode`, а потом `json_encode` с флагом `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`

Comment: Записываю переменную $body в файл и получаю: Text: {"update_id":561451718,
"message":{"message_id":313,"from":{"id":5676047177,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Marshall","username":"idaqipyshim7c","language_code":"ru"},"chat":{"id":5676047177,"first_name":"Marshall","username":"idaqipyshim7c","type":"private"},"date":1667722667,"text":"\u0442\u0435\u0441\u0442"}}

Comment: Метод json_decode и json_encode дает мне Ñ‚ÐµÑÑ такие кракозаблы

Comment: Починил. Суть была в том, что нужно для файла apidata.txt поставить кодировку utf8-bom